# Possible reasons for Structured Data items count decrease

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

The number of structured data items on our site fell from 4M to ~2M recently.
The parts of the site responsible for this data weren't changed in a long time and the general number of crawled/indexed pages didn't change either.
When testing the pages with Google Structure Data Testing, everything is OK, also, in Google Search Console I see that all items are OK: "0  Items with Errors"

Explanations I've found in the Internet, aren't really helpful - in most cases the problem is caused by errors in site's markup, which shouldn't be the case as we passed Google's tests, or in Google's servers error - but the last news about that are from 3 years ago, and everything was fixed in a week.
In our case it's been a month since the numbers fell.

What could other reasons for this problem be? Any ideas are welcome

Comment: We cannot really answer this without more info about mark-up and what you are expecting. For example, ratings in SERPs. Google changes how it uses mark-up in different ways from time to time. As well, with large updates in Googles algos, new metrics may effect how Google presents your site. It is not uncommon that mark-up in the SERPs disappear and then reappear. Google is making a lot of major updates this year. So without more information, we cannot even begin to guess.